# Liquibase updates on Redshift fail when run via CI/CD but are successful when ran manually

Tags: sql, continuous-integration, amazon-redshift, liquibase, aws-codebuild

So I am able to run liquibase updates directly from my machine they will run successfully, however when ran via aws code build they will fail, after going through logs I found that this error is what is causing the failures, when I run either update or changeLogSync

`liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))]`

I suspect that this statement fails because that table already exists. I verified this by going onto the cluster and querying the table

```
select * from databasechangeloglock;
 id | locked | lockgranted | lockedby 
----+--------+-------------+----------
  1 | f      |             | 
(1 row)
```

I set up a clean env by starting a new EC2 box and installing only the required drivers,extensions and liquibase client, and again this update ran successfully. Liquibase only seems to want to create DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK when run via code build.

Comment: Are you using the same user when running manually versus running via CICD?

Comment: Liquibase checks if the table exists by trying to create it and then catching the error to recognize that it already exists.

Are you on the newest version of liquibase and using the liquibase-redshift extension? There may be bugs fixed in newer versions to handle that better.

Otherwise, it seems like a bug. Could you include the stacktrace by running with --log-level=fine? You could log it at https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-redshift/issues for easier tracking as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact error with codefresh ci/cd pipeline with liquibase docker image(4.21.1). For me the workaround was to copy drivers liquibase-redshift-version.jar, redshift-jdbc-version.jar from my repo to lib folder on liquibase install location `/liquibase/internal/lib`(could be different based on your environment) before running
`liquibase update`.